# How to remove comma from string

Tags: php

I have string like this

```
$value = "abc , cde";
```

I want to remove that " , " from the sring and display like this

```
$value = "abc cde";
```

how to do this?

Comment: hove you googled this? have you tried anything? have you searched [the documentation](http://php.net/)

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer You know sir, my boss yelled me, so i confused, Totally forgot to google,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `str_replace` like

```
echo str_replace("," , " " , $value);
```

See this [**Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 3):

A simple [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) should work here:

If you want to remove the comma and the spaces around it and replace them with a single space:

```
$value = str_replace(" , ", " ", $value);
```

If you want to just remove the comma only and leave the spaces around it intact:

```
$value = str_replace(",", "", $value);
```

Answer (score 2):

str_replace
Here everything is in detail: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

Try using str_replace : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$value = str_replace(',', '', $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple function **[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)**

```
echo str_replace(",", "", $value);
```